# How to achieve this in LLVM?

Tags: pointers, compilation, llvm, elf

I need LLVM to update some pointers for me at specific regions. Assume I can use pragmas to provide additional information to compiler at those regions. Can the below logic be modified to the second snippet by LLVM while producing my output (shared object/executable)?

Original snippet:

```
char A[100];
....
char B[100];    
.....

#pragma CHANGE_A_TO_B

A[1] = 1;
A[100] = 100;
```

The output should be equivalent to logic of

```
char A[100];
....
char B[100];    
.....

/* LLVM must copy the contents and update pointers of A to B */    
strcpy(B,A); 

B[1] = 1;
B[100] = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done?
*Yes* it can be done.

you'll be replacing
`%store i32 1, %A`
or some bitcast version of this to something like
`%store i32 1, %B`

Look at some basic llvm passes to change and create IR instructions.

If the dependencies are not complicated you can probably get away using some script(perl or something else) to regex replace.

Comment: How about strcpy() insertion ? Can you help me with how to write with getOrInsertFunction() API of LLVM. The bit-cast etc makes it complicated for me, hence seeking help.